# Use coalesce inside ifelse in R

Tags: r

Could someone explain me the weird output of the following code?
I have a dataset with some NAs. I want to use the values in column C, if exists,
to fill the NAs in column B. The coalesce function is working properly when used
without the ifelse, but when used inside the ifelse function the results is weird.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- tibble(A = 1:3, 
            B = c("first", NA, "third"),
            C = c("first", "second", NA))

x %>%
    mutate(B = coalesce(B, C))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       A B      C     
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1     1 first  first 
#> 2     2 second second
#> 3     3 third  <NA>

x %>%
    mutate(B = ifelse(has_name(., "C"), coalesce(B, C), B))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       A B     C     
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1     1 first first 
#> 2     2 first second
#> 3     3 first <NA>
```

I solved the problem with the following code:

```
if(has_name(x, "C")){
    x %>%
        mutate(B = coalesce(B, C))
}           
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       A B      C     
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1     1 first  first 
#> 2     2 second second
#> 3     3 third  <NA>
```

But I'd like to use the if statement inside the mutate function. Any clarification is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `if/else` within `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
    mutate(B = if(has_name(., "C")) coalesce(B, C) else  B)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#       A B      C     
#  <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#1     1 first  first 
#2     2 second second
#3     3 third  <NA>
```

Note that `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same length, the `has_name` output is a logical vector of `length` 1 while the others are not.

Comment: Thank you! Which is the difference between ifelse and if/else?

Comment: @mchiapello the difference is that `if/else` is not vectorized i.e it takes a input logical vector of length 1 only where as `ifelse` can take `> 1`.  But there is a constraint i.e. all the arguments should be of same length or else recycling happens (if the objects are of different structure as well, then `if/else` is better)